# C# program to read, write, query xml

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to create a C# program to write, read, query xml file. I am very new to xml using C#. Can anyone please help me..

specifically i want to do this:

```
<streets>
<street1>
 <house1 no=1 color=red/>
</street1>
<street2>
 <house2 no=2 color=blue/>
</street2>
</streets>
```

I want to read this xml file and print all the houses and their properties.
I want to append to this xml file any new houses
I want to query where any specific house is located.

Can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ. Please have a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML. Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in creating an application to create some data on 'House' and want to have the capabilities of editing/updating, adding and removing such data, and also want to store it in XML, then it is simple. Here I am considering that you are not very interested to know the exact metadata of the XML and the XML need not be following some predefined schema.

For such a requirement I worked sometime back and you may look at this for the same:

http://www.geekays.net/post/2011/03/24/XML-Data-Storage-and-XmlSerializer-The-easy-data-store.aspx